# How to modify loop so as to take NaN values from values in columns in DataFrame in Pandas Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, if-statement

I have sample of my code in Python like below:

...

```
for col in df.columns.tolist():
    if val in df[f"{col}"].values:
       if val.isna():
          my_list.append(col)
```

So, if some column from my DataFrame contains NaN value add name of this column to "my_list".

I know that in my DF are columns with NaN values, but my code generate empty "my_list", probably the error is in line: `if val.isna():`, how can I modify that? How can I "tell" Python to take NaN values from columns ?

Comment: Try `df.columns[df.isna().sum() > 0]`

Comment: MYousefi could you implement your solution to my loop and show that ? :)

Comment: Oh sorry. That replaces the entire loop and returns the list of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a if col statement like this

```
for col in df.columns.tolist():
    if val in df[f"{col}"].values:
       if col == False:
          my_list.append(col)
```

I am not giving you the best way of doing it, just fixing your little list loop

Answer (score 0):

By iterating over the values in the column, adding the column name to my_list and then breaking you get this:

`my_list = ['col1','col3']`

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import NaN

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "col1":[10,2.5,NaN],
    "col2":[10,2.5,3.5],
    "col3":[5,NaN,1]})
my_list = []

for col in df.columns:
    for val in df[col].values:
        if pd.isna(val):
            my_list.append(col)
            break
print(f"{my_list=}")
```

Comment: Using your code I have problem beause: as many column names appear as there are nan, what can I do ?

Comment: I tried adding another NaN to col3, but didn't get the same result you did. Anyways, I would suggest using MYousefi's because it does the same without looping over the values in the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your code with changes that @Orange mentioned. I'm just adding this as an alternative. When working with data you want to allow the data base/data analysis software to do the heavy lifting. Looping over a cursor is something you should try to avoid as best as you can.

The code you have can be changed to:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].hasnans:
        my_list.append(col)
```

The code below functionally does the same thing:

```
df.columns[[df[col].hasnans for col in df.columns]].to_list()
```

The code below calculates `hasnans` using `isna` and `sum`.

```
df.columns[df.isna().sum() > 0].to_list()
```